# convert from 3 channels to 1 channel pytorch tensor from list of tensors

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Say I have a `list` of tensors, `volumes`, which I can iterate over:

```
    for volume in range(len(volumes)):
        print (volume.shape)



torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 222])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 185])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 271])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 261])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 215])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 284])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.Size([3, 512, 512, 191])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

How can I change the channel from 3 to 1, for all volumes?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'change to 1'? Do you like to create a gray scale volume?  or just remove 2 channels?

Comment: removing the first two channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like just to keep the first channel for each volume, you can create a new list like that:

```
new_volumes = [volume[0,...] for volume in volumes]
```

Comment: Not sure how you are *"removing the first two channels"* with this...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to remove the first two channels, then you should only keep the last one `dim=-1` *i.e.* `dim=2`:

```
>>> vnew = [v[2:] for v in volumes] # list of (1, 512, 512, *)
```

If you want to squeeze the singleton dimensions in the process then do:

```
>>> vnew = [v[2] for v in volumes] # list of (512, 512, *)
```